# Examples of non-Kähler compact complex manifolds of dimension four with some properties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am looking for examples of  non-Kähler compact complex manifolds of dimension four  with trivial canonical class and $H^i(M, {\mathcal O}_M) = H^0(M, \Omega^i_M) =0$ for $0< i < \dim M$.

In dimension two, no such manifolds exist (compact complex surfaces with trivial canonical class and $H^1(M, {\mathcal O}_M)=0$ are K3 surfaces and they are all Kähler.)

In dimension three, Infinitely many topological types have been constructed by R. Friedman.

My question is:
"Are there any examples of such manifolds in dimension four?"

It is notable that Guan constructed examples of non-Kähler compact complex symplectic fourfold with trivial canonical class.

Answer (score 3):

Examples were recently constructed by [Lee](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.12656.pdf) and [Sano](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.13437.pdf) by two different constructions (which both involve smoothing varieties with normal crossings).

Sano's paper also constructs examples in all dimensions $\geq 4$ with arbitrarily large second Betti number.